# jquery get p and span data and place in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="pricecard aircraft">
   <div class="card-body">
   <p>One way<br>
   <span class="onewayaircraftprice">£492.00</span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I use jquery to use the data in the p tag in to 2 variables?
ie

```
var1 = "One Way"
var2 = "£492.00"
```

my code

```
// This returns both data :(
var1 = $(this).children('.card-body').find('p').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

First option is to wrap `one way` by any tag. Then it's simple. Eg. `span:eq(0)` and `span:eq(1)`.

```js
// This returns both data :(
var span = $('.card-body').find('span:eq(1)').text();
var text = $('.card-body').find('span:eq(0)').text();

console.log(span)
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricecard aircraft">
   <div class="card-body">
   <p><span>One way</span><br>
   <span class="onewayaircraftprice">£492.00</span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

With your current HTML markup you can use for example this one

```
// This returns both data :(
var span = $('.card-body').find('span').text();
var text = $('.card-body').find('p').text().replace(span, '');

alert(text); // One way
alert(span); // £492.00
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to use $(this) as I'm doing this within a function.. how would I change to use  $(this) ?

Comment: @CraigJohnstone It's the same, `var span = $(this).find('.card-body span').text();`, `$(this).find('.card-body p')`, `$(this).find('.card-body span:eq(0)')`, etc.

Comment: thanks @pavel... I have other divs with the id of card-body.. how would I place all these figures in to an array instead of variables?

Comment: @CraigJohnstone array.push()